# Mail Message Panel

Tags: email

My mail-list panel usually shows but 5 or 6 previous emails with the message panel below. Was looking for a specific email and dragged the panel bar down to expose more previous emails. I "bumped" the bottom of the window which effectively closed the message panel . Now, I can't get the message panel back???
I move cursor to bottom of window and get the up-arrow-on-a-bar cursor but it doesn't close up the mails-list panel--cmd click, ctrl click, right click, nada.
How do I get my message panel back?   Clicking Window>Message Viewer does nothing.
Yes, I use, and prefer, classic layout.

Comment: No, cmd O does nothing.

Comment: BTW--I'm obviously talking about  classic layout.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you are looking for?

[image]

Cmd + O or Window > Message Viewer should open a new window.